# taking the last element of a vector and moving it to another vector

Tags: c++, vector, move

I am trying to move the last element of the vector `old_balls` to the new vector `new_balls`.

But when I call the function, it doesn't move the element to the new vector.

I think I am using the move function correctly.

```
std::vector<ball*> old_balls;
std::vector<ball*> new_balls;

void move(std::vector <ball*> ball_box, std::vector <ball*> n_ball_box ){
    new_ball_.push_back(std::move(ball_box[0]));
}

//function call

move(old_balls, new_balls);
```

**UPDATE**: with the below code, I expect `new_balls` to have one element of `old_balls`, but I get a buffer overflow:

Balls.hpp

```
Private:
    std::vector<ball*> new_balls;

    void move(std::vector<ball*> ball_box)
    {
        ball* b = ball_box.front();
        ball_box.erase(ball_box.begin());
        new_balls.push_back(b); //don't have to pass new ball because it's member variable
    }
```

This is how I call the function in `Main.cpp`:

```
std::vector<ball*> old_balls; //This has 30 ball* elements.

...

ball object;
object.move(old_balls);
```

Comment: `move` should take the `vector`s by reference. You should `erase` the first element of `ball_box` after moving from it.

Comment: It moves the pointer as told, what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @senpai your edit completely invalidated my answer. So I reverted the edit and re-posted it in another manner for you.  For future reference, please don't change your questions after people start answering them. You can always add new details, but please don't remove/change details that people are referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the vectors *by value*, so you are acting on *copies* of the vectors, not on the *original* vectors.  You need to pass the vectors *by reference* instead.

Also, you said you wanted to move the *last* element, but you are actually moving the *first* element instead.  And you are not removing the element from the old vector.

Also, there is no need to use `std::move()` with raw pointers.  Why are you using `ball*` at all?  You should be using `std::unique_ptr<ball>` instead.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
void move(std::vector<ball*> &ball_box, std::vector<ball*> &n_ball_box)
{
    ball* b = ball_box.back();
    ball_box.pop_back();
    n_ball_box.push_back(b);
}
```

If you really want to move the *first* element, then it would look like this instead:

```cpp
void move(std::vector<ball*> &ball_box, std::vector<ball*> &n_ball_box)
{
    ball* b = ball_box.front();
    ball_box.erase(ball_box.begin());
    n_ball_box.push_back(b);
}
```

That said, if you switch to `std::unique_ptr<ball>`, then it would look more like this:

```cpp
using ball_ptr = std::unique_ptr<ball>;

void move(std::vector<ball_ptr> &ball_box, std::vector<ball_ptr> &n_ball_box)
{
    ball_ptr b = std::move(ball_box.back());
    ball_box.pop_back();
    /* or:
    ball_ptr b = std::move(ball_box.front());
    ball_box.erase(ball_box.begin());
    */
    n_ball_box.push_back(std::move(b));
}

std::vector<ball_ptr> old_balls;
std::vector<ball_ptr> new_balls;
...
move(old_balls, new_balls);
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to use a for loop to move the vector to avoid having a buffer overflow?

Comment: If you want to move more than 1 element at a time, then of course you would need a loop (a `while` loop may make more sense than a `for` loop, though). But the fact that you had to ask that makes me think this is moving into [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) territory. What are you REALLY trying to accomplish here?

Comment: the new_ball is actually a private member of a class. And I am trying to move one element from a vector from another to the private vector member. But I thought that I should just use a function that takes to parameters since it won't make any difference and I just need to implement a getter. but I always get a buffer overflow when I call the function and run the code

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong, but we can't see what you are actually doing. Please edit your question to provide more details so you can get a more appropriate answer.

Comment: You are still passing the `old_balls` to `move()` *by value*, you need to pass it *by reference* instead. And you are not checking if the `ball_box` parameter is empty before trying to moving the first (why not last?) element from it.  Calling `front()` (or `back()`), or `erase(begin())` (or `pop_back()`), on an empty vector is *undefined behavior*. Also, what you have shown is not a [mcve], so it is difficult to diagnose why you are getting a buffer overflow.

Comment: But new ball is supposed to be empty. And old ball has 30 elements. But I think my problem is that I am using push_back on the empty vector new balls. But aren't I supposed to use push black on an empty vector?

Answer (score 0):

```
        myNewVector.push_back(currVector.back());
        currVector.pop_back();
```

pop_back() cant return any values,
so we fitches last element of our vector first, then pop it..